# Uncaught ReferenceError: jqXHR is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to submit login form(which is a popup div) using jquery. If form validation fails then I want display error message on popup div only and stop closing that form(popup) as page gets reload when ajax call enters error function. 
Here is my js code

```
$("#loginForm").submit(function(e) {
    var email    = $(".log-email").val();
    var password = $(".log-pass").val();

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/login",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {password:password, email:email},
        success : function(data){
            console.log(data);
            window.location.href= data.redirecturl;
        },
        error:function(XMLHttpRequest,jqXHR, thrownError,ajaxOptions){
            var errors = XMLHttpRequest.responseJSON;
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
            if(errors)
            {
                $(".login-error").text(errors.email);
                $(".login-error").css("color","red");
            }
            // e.preventDefault();
            jqXHR.error();
            return false;
        }
    });
    // .fail(function(){
    //     e.preventDefault();
    //     e.stopPropagation();
    // });
});
```

and blade(HTML) code looks like,

```
<form id="loginForm">
    {{ Form::email('email', null, ['class' => 'vbg-input log-email', 'maxlength' => '191', 'required' => 'required', 'autofocus' => 'autofocus', 'placeholder' => trans('validation.attributes.frontend.email')]) }}

    {{ Form::password('password', ['class' => 'vbg-input log-pass', 'required' => 'required', 'placeholder' => trans('validation.attributes.frontend.password')]) }}

    <a href="" class="forgot-passw">Forgot Your Password?</a>
    <button class="sign-in hover-animation">
         <span> {{trans('labels.frontend.auth.login_button')}} </span>
    </button>
</form>
```

I tried various ways but no success without error. When I use **jqXHR.error();** I am able to stop closing form, but it gives me an error message in the console as,

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jqXHR is not defined
at Object.error (script.js?v=1527662366599:148)
at fire (frontend.js?id=a613937eec44062691cf:7349)
at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (frontend.js?id=a613937eec44062691cf:7479)
at done (frontend.js?id=a613937eec44062691cf:13306)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (frontend.js?id=a613937eec44062691cf:13538)
```

Really got stuck at this point. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The param you add `jqxhr` but inside function you call `jqXHR`.

Answer (score 1):

As per jQuery document see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> error: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )

So need to change to

```
error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bhumi/rwe705ry/

Comment: Tried error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) but got error as "Uncaught TypeError: jqXHR.error is not a function"

Comment: yeah there is no function .error, you can use .fail

Comment: try use console.log(jqXHR) see detail.

Comment: @BhumiShah Tried fail as well but still then form gets closed on error

Comment: are you using bootstrap form modalbox? share your form

Comment: @BhumiShah No I have  div which opens on button click. I have edited my code

Comment: @Amarja: As per conversation, i have created sample code for you!! please check

Comment: Thanks @BhumiShah, Everything is working great but the problem is with my popup div. When I debug line by line by adding breakpoints then I can see error message but after completing ajax... I don't know how page gets reloaded and due to this popup gets closed.